# getStaticProps does not fetch from the url but postman gives it the data I need

Tags: reactjs, next.js

It's like that I'm trying to download the last 3 news. But when I try to do this then no content comes out at all or in other words it gives me "undefined" in relation to that data.

I have tried to do this:

```
import { siteName, env } from "../../../../comps/env";
export default function NewsGridThree({ newsthreeData }) {
    console.log("Data: " + newsthreeData)
    const newTitle = "Nyheder";
    return (
        <div className="mobil:mb-6">
            <h2 className="text-2xl font-extrabold uppercase text-center text-blue-500 mt-2 mb-10">{newTitle}</h2>
            <div className="grid md:grid-cols-12 gap-2 px-5">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${env.baseURL}${siteName.NewsThree}`);
    console.log(res)
    const newsthreeData = await res.json();
    console.log(newsthreeData);
    return {
        props: {
            newsthreeData
        }
    }
}
```

Both by res and newsthreeData it gives me nothing in my console.log.

Do I use postman to make sure if content is coming or not. Then content will appear which can be seen below.

```
{
    "isSuccess": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Test 2",
            "url": "Test-2",
            "deck": "test-2",
            "text": "test",
            "createDate": "26-11-2021",
            "viewCount": 50,
            "tags": "test2, test-all",
            "newsDataCategoriId": 3,
            "imgValue": "test.png",
            "newsDataCategori": null
        },
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

i have also tried to take the url that i use in postman and use it at fetch, but it still comes up together.

How can I solve this problem in relation to being able to reach the goal? - I have tried to take postman url and use in fetch, I have also tried to see if it was due to env and sitename that the error was.

Comment: hi  put getStaticProps on function "NewsGridThree" , if you want got Url , you shuold use  getStaticPaths

Comment: What u mean @H9ee i cant not see what u mean,

Comment: can you log the url you are fetching as well?

Comment: nop i have try this @ChemiAdel

Comment: Where are you checking the `console.log` output? `getStaticProps` runs on the server and as such it outputs to the terminal where you started your dev server. It won't log anything to the browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

put getStaticProps on function frist

if you have dynamic route, [www.example.com/news](http://www.example.com/news)
create folder by name news and put on create JS by name [news].js

so have got url in getStaticProps

```
import { siteName, env } from "../../../../comps/env";
 const NewsGridThree = ({ newsthreeData }) => {
    console.log("Data: " + newsthreeData)
    const newTitle = "Nyheder";
    return (
        <div className="mobil:mb-6">
            <h2 className="text-2xl font-extrabold uppercase text-center text-blue-500 mt-2 mb-10">{newTitle}</h2>
            <div className="grid md:grid-cols-12 gap-2 px-5">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return { paths: [], fallback: "blocking" }

}
export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
    const {news} = params.qoury
    \\ news its url if you want 
    \\ if you have static url, so delete getStaticPaths create your route in build time
    const res = await fetch(`${env.baseURL}${siteName.NewsThree}`);
    console.log(res)
    const newsthreeData = await res.json();
    console.log(newsthreeData);
    return {
        props: {
            newsthreeData
        }
    }
}
export default NewsGridThree
```

Comment: As things are right now, I do not need what you have written / made. It's just to show 3 news on the front page.

Comment: so you need create 3 page for 3 news by name